# Compose Desktop application crashing: ClassNotFoundException: java.net.http.HttpClient

Tags: java, compose-desktop, jetbrains-compose

I want to use the java.net.http package in my compose desktop application. When I run the application in IntelliJ, everything works fine. But when I build a .deb file using packageDeb and install it via apt, the application crashes due to a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.net.http.HttpClient` when I click on the "Start" button.

Here's the example code:

```
import androidx.compose.desktop.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.Button
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.window.Window
import androidx.compose.ui.window.application
import java.net.http.HttpClient

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
            Button(onClick = {
                println("getting httpClient")
                val httpClient: HttpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient()
            }) {
                Text(text = "Start")
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() = application {
    Window(onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication) {
        App()
    }
}
```

And the build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.compose
import org.jetbrains.compose.desktop.application.dsl.TargetFormat
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.6.10"
    id("org.jetbrains.compose") version "1.0.1"
}

group = "some.group"
version = "1.0"

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
}

dependencies {
    implementation(compose.desktop.currentOs)
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "16"
}

compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "untitled"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this? java.net.http should be available in Java 16..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can have a try like this

```
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"
        nativeDistributions {
        targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "untitled"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
            modules("java.net.http")
        }
    }
}
```